Logistic regression power analysis
I'm replicating a study that looks at the effect of mitochondrial DNA copy number on AD.
I am required to do a power analysis to estimate the sample size needed for the study. I am using the effect size in the study to do a logistic regression power analysis. The effect size that was reported in the study was a hazards ratio of 1.65. From my understanding, I have to convert that to an odds ratio or Cohen's d. Is that correct? I'm also a bit confused on how to proceed from there. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

One thing to keep in mind when doing a power analysis based on an estimate is that if you use a calculation that assumes it's a population parameter, the resulting sample size will be smaller than it should be.
